# I know the problem is with the sum function but I have no idea on how to fix it

Tags: sql-server

Error message:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Code:

```
Select dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations 
    , SUM(Convert(int, vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (Partition by dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date) as RollingPeopleVaccinated
From project..['covid deaths$'] dea
Join project..['covid vacinations$'] vac
   On dea.location = vac.location
   and dea.date = vac.date
where dea.continent is not null
order by 2,3;
```

Comment: *"I have no idea on how to fix it"* Use a `bigint` instead, or perhaps a `decimal` with a scale of `0`.

Comment: Some recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal), [Bad Habits to Kick : Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). Also, I really recommend a better name for your objects than one that has single quotes in its name and must be delimit identified. `CovidDeaths` or `covid_vacinations` would be far better options as examples.

Comment: From your identifiers it looks like the source might be an Excel workbook. Those often contain out-of-range, incorrect or garbage values, depending on how the import was done, so aside from what Larnu said (which applies if the numbers are correct but simply too large to fit in an `INT`) you may also want to check the data itself for anomalies, with something like `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, new_vaccinations) IS NULL` (`FLOAT` is not the right type for your `SUM`, but likely the type used in Excel).

Comment: China has given 3.41Billion doses of vaccinations so if that is one of your locations you're gonna need to use `bigint`. Most you can get in an `int` is `2,147,483,647`

Comment: Why are you converting data types on the fly? I would strongly suggest you fix the data model in the first place.